# Jwplayer not running in Firefox

Tags: firefox, jwplayer

This problem has been covered many times but none of suggested solutions worked for me so I decided to post this question again with a link to my site.

Please, check a sample webpage: http://miejska.tv/sinfonia-varsovia-zamienia-noc-w-dzien,wywiady,65.html

In chrome everything works 100%, all the time. The JWplayer shows up on the page, files are loaded and played correctly. In Firefox 90% of the time the JWPlayer shows up in half with an error message "error loading player. no playable sources found". Similar situation is with IE. Though problem occurs less often and after page refresh everything works ok.

I have updated the browsers and played with their settings, including change of safe mode of flash in Firefox. In vein.

Maybe there is some other code on the page that causes conflicts with JWPlayer. Maybe the problem lies somewhere else.

Please, have a look and help. Otherwise I'll have to switch to other player as Firefox in my country shares 50% of the market yet.

Witold

Comment: OSD is deprecated `<iframe id="google_osd_static_frame_8284568671433" name="google_osd_static_frame" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></iframe>`

Comment: Use either `https://` or `http://` for protocol do not mix them on the same page. Your fonts need `https://` protocol if possible.

Comment: Do you mean I cannot use different mp4 sources in the same jwplayer config? For example: http://file.mp4, https://youtube and rtmp://otherfile.mp4.

Comment: The protocols on your media are fine, it's `http://` and `https://` being on the same page is one of the factors that contribute to Firefox's poor performance and capabilities. There are security warnings that other browsers just log, Firefox has a tendency to break if there are enough security errors and/or warnings. OSD I believe is a deprecated Google Ads script. Anything deprecated can inhibit Firefox, and it's common to see Chrome uninhibited and Firefox to fail for no apparent reason.

Comment: I checked my google adsense code and it's up-to-date. I deleted some iframe code from a third party. I also changed protocol to https. Maybe I miss something else, but the player is still not loading properly. Any other ideas?

Comment: The last version I used before my company decided to replace JW was 7. There was increasing complaints from clients who had an older generation Macs that never could get Firefox working with JW. It had to do with Mozilla having paranoid delusions of MP4 royalties that may or may not come in the future. Are you using a Mac and if so, can you play YouTube with JW? TBH, the site is slow but I'm from the US and in an isolated part of it, so my connections are inconsistent.

Comment: I'm working on a standard PC with win7 OS. In my country the page loads pretty quick. Wich player did you switch for after JW?

Comment: Plain HTML5 with custom skin. It was very hard to develop, fortunately my clients are required to use Chrome, Firefox, or Safari only.

Comment: I think I have found the source of the problem. It's jquery. After removal from page code the jwplayer started working. <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: Unfortunately, other jquery dependant elements stopped working now.

Comment: jQuery is currently at 3.1 you definitely need to upgrade. Your jQuery is very old, so you probably have some deprecated or even obsolete code. In order to avoid refactoring everything, you can use the [jQuery Migrate](https://jquery.com/download/#jquery-migrate-plugin) plugin before you upgrade to 3.0 (There's some extra fix you have to do if you want to continue to 3.1)

Comment: that's probably the way to go. in the meantime I digged deep into custom jquery code and noticed that I used the same reference name to different objects, after fixing it the player started working in firefox. thank you for all your help.

Comment: That's great I'm glad you got it working.